# Magento 2 - Use Redis in Full Page Cache

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, redis

I check similar question but I am unable to find command to add Redis server for full page cache.

The command to add Redis for backend cache is following:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --cache-backend-redis-server=xxxxxxxx --cache-backend-redis-db=0
```

I want to use **Redis** for **Full Page Cache** what would be the **command** to do this?

Comment: Please pay attention  the Redis can be used only for build in FPC, that do not recommended to use in production.

Comment: Then why it is defined in devdocs? And why my website's performance is much better after applying it?

Comment: I am using Redis from AWS elasticache

Comment: Yes, please see recommendations https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/software.html#varnish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution.

## For Backend cache on Redis

use below sample command

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --cache-backend=redis --cache-backend-redis-server=xxxxxxxxxxx --cache-backend-redis-db=0
```

## For Page Cache on Redis

use below sample command

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --page-cache=redis --page-cache-redis-server=xxxxxxxxxxx --page-cache-redis-db=1
```

Both cache could be save on same redis server but it will use different **databases 0 and 1**

**Note: For local redis cache, use 127.0.0.1**